# How do I display images saved in MongoDB through Express.js through React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, image, express

Something is causing my product images to render as a tiny black box or as broken images.

For example, suppose I'm trying to show this:
[image]

Well, it ends up showing this:
[image]
[image]

So, product in Products collection:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5f35bf52a6f23e560250d322"), 
   "photo" : { "data" : BinData(0,"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA...), "contentType" : "image/jpeg" }, 
   "variations" : [ 
        ObjectId("5f35bf52a6f23e560250d324"), 
        ObjectId("5f35bf52a6f23e560250d325"), 
        ObjectId("5f35bf52a6f23e560250d323") ], 
   "name" : "Carrot Juice", 
   "description" : "Carrot juice!", 
   "category" : ObjectId("5f339503ca7d362b44305a8b"), 
   "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T22:31:46.903Z"), 
   "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T22:31:46.983Z"), 
   "__v" : 0 
}
```

Controller (*assume `req.product` is `5f35bf52a6f23e560250d322`*):

```
exports.productById = (req, res, next, id) => {
    Product.findById(id)
        .populate("category")
        .populate("variations")
        .lean()
        .exec((err, product) => {
            if (err || !product) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: "Product not found"
                });
            } else { req.product = product; next(); }
        });
};


exports.photo = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.product.photo.data) {
        res.set("Content-Type", req.product.photo.contentType);
        console.log(`req.product.photo.data: `, req.product.photo.data);
        return res.send(req.product.photo.data);
    }
    next();
};
```

Route:

```
router.get("/product/photo/:productId", photo);
```

The `Card` Component (React), that renders `<ShowImage />`:

```
import ShowImage from './ShowImage'

const Card = ({ product }) => {

    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header name">{product.name}</div>
            <div className="card-body">
                <ShowImage item={product} url="product" />
           
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Card;
```

The`ShowImage` Component, which serves `http://<host_ip>/api/product/photo/5f35bf52a6f23e560250d322` :

```
import React from "react";
import { API } from "../config";

const ShowImage = ({ item, url }) => (
    <div className="product-img">
        <img
            src={`${API}/${url}/photo/${item._id}`}
            alt={item.name}
            className="mb-3"
            style={{ maxHeight: "100%", maxWidth: "100%" }}
        />
    </div>
);

export default ShowImage;
```

So, it's supposed to display the product image from a url like so: `http://<host_ip>/api/product/photo/5f35bf52a6f23e560250d322`

But now, it shows like this:
[image]

I thought maybe `photo` is missing from the document but that's impossible since Buffer data shows in console whenever I call it, see:
[image]

Why is this not displaying the image from express on this url?

UPDATE: And... sticking in a random image url off some website in ShowImage resulted in that image showing up successfully so i KNOW that's fishy...

Still this url does not load the image in the browser:
`http://<host_ip>/api/product/photo/5f35bf52a6f23e560250d322`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!  The issue was including `.lean()` in `productById`.  Here is the corrected code of `productById` which then resulted in the images properly rendering:

```
exports.productById = (req, res, next, id) => {
    Product.findById(id)
        .populate("category")
        .populate("variations")
        .exec((err, product) => {
            if (err || !product) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: "Product not found"
                });
            } else { req.product = product; next(); }
        });
};
```